# How to use using in fillCommand?

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlcommand

I want to use `using`  for `sql command`:

```
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("usp_UpdateUser", _sqlConnection, _sqlTransaction))
{
   ....
}
```

But in `FillCommand(ref command)` I am getting exception:

`Cannot pass command as ref or out variable because it is using variable.`

My code is:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("usp_UpdateUser", _sqlConnection,  
          _sqlTransaction);

command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = Id;

FillCommand(ref command);
try
{
     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch
{
     throw;
}
```

Comment: What is FillCommand in this case? Is that a function that you wrote?

Comment: Yes FillCommand is my function

Comment: @lakki LOL, trippino is asking you to post the definition of the `FillCommand` you are using. It is probably not `void FillCommand(ref SqlCommand command) { ... }`;

Answer (score 2):

Since

```
FillCommand
```

is a function that you wrote and you are using it as a `void` function, you can modify it in order to let it return the command instead of passing it as `ref` parameter.

Use something like this:

```
using(SqlCommand command = FillCommand("usp_UpdateUser", _sqlConnection, _sqlTransaction, CommandType.StoredProcedure))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: My idea too. Then you just call FillCommand in the using statement.

Comment: yep exactly, the function has to take all the parameters to instantiate the whole command of course